# return the value in toString

Tags: java, encapsulation

How do i return this value into may main function? sorry i just started learning encapsulation in java.

```
public String toString() {
  System.out.format("%02d/", day);
  System.out.format("%02d/", month);
  System.out.format("%02d/", year);
  
  return toString;
}
```

***Input:*** `1/1/1972`

***Output:*** `toString cannot be resovled to a variable return toString;`

***Expected output:*** `01/01/1972`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to use the `format()` function that is defined in the `String` class.

for example

```
public String toString() {
 String date = String.format("%02d/", day);
 date += String.format("%02d/", month);
 date += String.format("%02d/", year);


 return date;
}
```

In your original function you were just outputting text to the console, and you did not define a variable to be returned.

Hopefully this solves your issue.

Comment: Or better `public String toString() {
        return String.format("%02d/%02d/%02d", day, month, year);
    }`